# Using strtok while rewriting CSV archives for Excel

Tags: c, csv

I'm trying to write an Excel archive(input) into an empty archive. The aim is to write a new Excel without the dates, but when I try, the new archive is erasing some lines in the excel and not erasing the dates as I wanted to. Is it something with the code?

**Input**

```
1760   
02/20/18,11403.7    
02/19/18,11225.3   
02/18/18,10551.8   
02/17/18,11112.7
02/16/18,10233.9
02/15/18,10166.4
02/14/18,9494.63
02/13/18,8598.31
```

**Actual Output**

```
1760   
02/20/18   
11403.7    
02/19/18    
11225.3    
02/18/18    
10551.8    
02/17/18    
11112.7    
02/16/18    
10233.9    
02/15/18    
10166.4    
02/14/18    
9494.63    
02/13/18    
8598.31
```

**Expected Output**

```
1760   
11403.7    
11225.3   
10551.8   
11112.7   
10233.9   
10166.4  
9494.63  
8598.31
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    FILE *btc;
    FILE *out;

        if((out = fopen("new.csv", "w")) == NULL ){
            printf("not found new\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if((btc = fopen("BTC.csv", "r")) == NULL  ){
            printf("not found btc\n");
            exit(1);
        }                           
                    long int a;
                    char linha[256];
                    char *token = NULL;

                    while (!feof(btc))
                    {

                    fgets(linha, 256, btc);
                    token = strtok(linha, ",\n"); 

                            while ((token != NULL) && (!feof(btc)))
                            {
                            a++;
                            fprintf(out, "%s\n", token);
                            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                            }
                    }


    fclose(btc);
    fclose(out);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those pictures should be reduced to the text that is in column A of the spreadsheet and shown as 'code' in the question.  You probably only need 5-10 rows from each.

Comment: It would be better to open the input file first, before you create the output file.  That way you don't leave empty files around if you can't open the input file.

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/) for a discussion of why your loop control is wrong.  You need to test `fgets()` — forget `feof()`.  Your input comes with multiple entries per input line; your output is splitting each line into multiple lines.  It isn't clear if that's really your intention.  You have `char num;
                fscanf(btc, "%c", &num);` — why do you ignore the first character in the file?  (And your indentation is erratic — try to get it straight; it makes it easier for everyone, especially you.)

Comment: (Partial repeat of my first comment) It would be helpful if you showed your input — not the picture — and the expected and actual outputs, and gave a clearer explanation than "it is all wrong" for what is the difference between expected and actual output.  This is an important part of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: See my answer — assume that if you are using `feof()` in a loop you are doing it wrong.  A while ago, I searched through 30 years of my C code and found a couple of places (out of several thousand files) where I used `feof()`, and it was always used after a loop had terminated because of an I/O error, and I used `feof()` to distinguish between EOF and a real error (which could be tested with `ferror()`).  All your indentation is erratic except the two lines declaring `btc` and `out`, the two `fclose()` calls and the `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want to drop the date field, which is the first field.  You need to arrange not to print the first token found by `strtok()` on each line — except the first where you should probably print 1760 by not scanning the `1` as a separate operation.

That leads to code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *name1 = "BTC.csv";
    const char *name2 = "new.csv";
    FILE *out;
    FILE *btc;

    if ((btc = fopen(name1, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s for reading\n", name1);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((out = fopen(name2, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s for writing\n", name2);
        exit(1);
    }

    int lineno = 0;
    char linha[256];
    char *token = NULL;

    while (fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), btc) != 0)
    {
        if (++lineno == 1)
            fprintf(out, "%s", linha);
        else
        {
            token = strtok(linha, ",\n");
            if (token == NULL)
                break;
            while ((token = strtok(NULL, ",\n")) != 0)
                fprintf(out, "%s\n", token);
        }
    }

    fclose(btc);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Given input file `BTC.csv`:

```
1760
02/20/18,11403.7
02/19/18,11225.3
02/18/18,10551.8
02/17/18,11112.7
02/16/18,10233.9
02/15/18,10166.4
02/14/18,9494.63
02/13/18,8598.31
```

the program creates output file `new.csv`:

```
1760
11403.7
11225.3
10551.8
11112.7
10233.9
10166.4
9494.63
8598.31
```

This seems to correspond to what is wanted.